# Multi-condition Nginx Redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, redirect, amazon-cloudfront

In nginx, I am trying to find out the best way to handle a redirect to force all non-https traffic to https if and only if the the traffic is not in the /assets/* path.

USE CASE: To enable javascript and css to be cached via AWS CloudFront without having to chain the SSL cert from the server.

Here is what I am trying:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto = "http" ) {
        set $redir please_redir;
    }

    location ~ ^/assets/|favicon.ico {
        set $redir  dont_redir;
        root /home/deploy/www/public;
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }


    if ( $redir = please_redir ) {
        return  301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

I tried wrapping 'please_redir' in quotes as well, with no luck. Any ideas?  Other workable solutions are welcome.  Keep in mind, it has to be a non-https request as well as NOT in the /assets/ path.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the location of the redirect. Silly mistake... For anyone looking to send the rails asset pipeline via CloudFront, you will have an issue on woff and tiff files with CORS, and you will need to send additional headers for allowing the origin request. We opted to serve static assets over http to cloudfront to avoid having to chain the SSL certificate within CloudFront. Here is the solution.

```
server {
    listen  80;

    location ~ ^/assets/|favicon.ico|robots.txt {
        root /home/deploy/www/public;
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
        if ($http_origin ~* 'https?://subdomain\.cloudfront.net') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
        }
    }

    location / {

        # ELB Injects:  X-Forwarded-Proto: HTTP or HTTPS
        if ( $http_x_forwarded_proto = "http" ) {
            return  301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
        }

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set up your primary server to listen only to https, and a separate server on http for redirects and assets.

Additional server config may look like

```
server {
  server_name  example.com;

  location ~ ^/assets/|favicon.ico {
    root /home/deploy/www/public;
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location / {
    rewrite ^(.*) https://example.com$1 permanent;
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue here is, all requests are coming in on port 80 (ssl is offloaded at the load balancer).  You can see in my code that I am relying on http_x_forwarded_proto

Comment: Then try moving condition inside `/` location (and rewrite straight away, without variables)

Answer (score 0):

Use ^~ and = locations for the best performance. The repeated static content directives are worth it. You can always put them in an included file for ease of maintainence:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/deploy/www/public;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        gzip_static on;
        expires max;
        add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it didn't exactly answer the question, but it did lead me to the solution. The redirect was in the wrong place.